# Crontab R script failing due to import function (Rstudio is closed)

Tags: r, cron, rscript

I am trying to run a Rscript using crontab with Rstudio closed and i am getting the following error in the log when the script is ran:

```
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.0.2 
Error in import("~/Desktop/R/Projects/TestFile.csv",  : 
  could not find function "import"
Execution halted
```

From my limited knowledge of crontab functionality it is my understanding that the 'import' function can only work with Rstudio open. Is there a way to get around this such as using an alternative function that imports a file that can be read using crontab?

Note: The script works when run in Rstudio.

EDIT:

Crontab instruction:

```
if (!require("cronR")) {
  install.packages("cronR")
  library(cronR)
}

cron_clear(ask=FALSE)

f <- "~/Desktop/R/Projects/MyRCode.R"
cmd <- cron_rscript(f)
cmd

cron_add(cmd, frequency = "daily", id = "test", at = "16:30")
```

Rscript:

```
library("miniUI")
library("shinyFiles")
library(quantmod)

if (!require("httr")) {
  install.packages("httr")
  library(httr)
}

if (!require("jsonlite")) {
  install.packages("jsonlite")
  library(jsonlite)
}

if (!require("gsubfn")) {
  install.packages("gsubfn")
  library(gsubfn)
}

if (!require("rjson")) {
  install.packages("rjson")
  library(rjson)
}

if (!require("RJSONIO")) {
  install.packages("RJSONIO")
  library(RJSONIO)
}

library(dplyr)

rio_csv <- import("~/Desktop/R/Projects/TestFile.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- data.frame("Ticker" = rio_csv[,1],"Amount" = rio_csv[,3], "Shares" = rio_csv[,6],"Average"= rio_csv[,8])

write_json(df,"~/Desktop/R/Projects/JSONFile.json")
```

Comment: It'd be useful to have a look a 2 things: 1) The `crontab` command through which the script is run. 2) The script itself.

Comment: I have added an Edit section with the information you require. I have a number of packages that i wish to use to expand the code, hence a long list of packages selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function import is from the rio package. Your automated script fails because you did not load that package rio as in `library(rio)`. This could not even have worked in RStudio itself neither if you did not load package rio.

Comment: Unfortunately i am still getting the same error even with rio added.

Comment: I don't believe you.

Comment: I m sorry to read that, but it is the case. Does the rio package work in crontab when Rstudio is closed in which case this may be still causing the error.

Comment: Of course, looks to me like you haven't got that package rio installed as the root user

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

install.packages("rio")
install_formats()